# SQL delta calculation with varying records

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am calculating the difference of amounts between batch runs of `calc_table` and store it in  `delta_table`. The number of records in `calc_table` per batch run can vary.

I can calculate the difference, but I am not sure how to handle new or deleted records since the JOINS in SQL would be different. I believe I need to use a FULL JOIN but I am having a problem constructing the SQL query.

Note: batch_id is not always incremented by 1. And the query should be in the `calc_table` since that is where the amount is stored. The `delta_table` will contain the differences between amounts of calc_table.

This is my current SQL: (I am using PostgreSQL)

```
select c2.batch_id, c2.c_id, c2.date, 
       (c2.amount1 - c1.amount1) as amount1, (c2.amount2 - c1.amount2) as amount2
from calc_table c1 inner join calc_table c2 on c1.c_id = c2.c_id 
where c1.batch_id = 100 and c2.batch_id = 101

* c1.batch_id and c2.batch_id are PARAMETERS.
```

And this is giving me all the expected c_id (with deleted and new records). But i cannot construct it properly to give me my expected results for the delta calculation.

```
SELECT coalesce(c2.c_id, c1.c_id) as c_id
FROM
  (select * from calc_table where batch_id = 100) c1
FULL OUTER JOIN
  (select * from calc_table where batch_id = 101) c2
ON c1.id = c2.id
group by coalesce(c2.c_id, c1.c_id);
```

---

This is the first run of the calc_table: (batch_id = 100)

```
calc_table:
-----------------------------------------------------
id | batch_id | c_id | date       | amount1 | amount2
-----------------------------------------------------
1  | 100      | C001 | 2017-03-01 | 100     | 200 
2  | 100      | C002 | 2017-03-01 | 100     | 200 
3  | 100      | C003 | 2017-03-01 | 100     | 200
```

If the user runs again: (batch_id = 101)

```
4  | 101      | C001 | 2017-03-01 | 200     | 200 
5  | 101      | C002 | 2017-03-01 | 150     | 220 
6  | 101      | C003 | 2017-03-01 | 170     | 250 
7  | 101      | C004*| 2017-03-01 | 210     | 250  

* C004 is a new record
```

Delta between them (batch_id 101 minus 100) should be calculated and stored in delta_table:

```
delta_table:
------------------------------------------------------
id | batch_id | c_id | date       | amount1 | amount2 
------------------------------------------------------
1  | 101      | C001 | 2017-03-01 | 100     | 0       
2  | 101      | C002 | 2017-03-01 | 50      | 20      
3  | 101      | C003 | 2017-03-01 | 70      | 50      
4  | 101      | C004 | 2017-03-01 | 210     | 250
```

---

If the user runs again: (batch_id = 104, id 8-10)

```
* Rows 1-7 (same as before)

calc_table:
-----------------------------------------------------
id | batch_id | c_id | date       | amount1 | amount2
-----------------------------------------------------
1  | 100      | C001 | 2017-03-01 | 100     | 200 
2  | 100      | C002 | 2017-03-01 | 100     | 200 
3  | 100      | C003 | 2017-03-01 | 100     | 200 
4  | 101      | C001 | 2017-03-01 | 200     | 200 
5  | 101      | C002 | 2017-03-01 | 150     | 220 
6  | 101      | C003 | 2017-03-01 | 170     | 250 
7  | 101      | C004 | 2017-03-01 | 210     | 250  

8  | 104      | C001 | 2017-03-01 | 200     | 200 
9  | 104      | C002 | 2017-03-01 | 400     | 200 
10 | 104      | C003 | 2017-03-01 | 400     | 220 

* Note: C004 was deleted
```

Delta between them (batch_id 104 minus 101) should be calculated and stored in delta_table:

```
* Rows 1-4 (same as before), new delta = id 5-8

delta_table:
------------------------------------------------------
id | batch_id | c_id | date       | amount1 | amount2 
------------------------------------------------------
1  | 101      | C001 | 2017-03-01 | 100     | 0       
2  | 101      | C002 | 2017-03-01 | 50      | 20      
3  | 101      | C003 | 2017-03-01 | 70      | 50      
4  | 101      | C004 | 2017-03-01 | 210     | 250     

5  | 104      | C001 | 2017-03-01 | 0       | 0       
6  | 104      | C002 | 2017-03-01 | 250     | -20     
7  | 104      | C003 | 2017-03-01 | 230     | -30     
8  | 104      | C004 | 2017-03-01 | -210    | -250
```

Comment: *I can calculate the difference, but I am not sure how to handle new or deleted records.* -- you don't have to handle anything like that in a `SELECT`. If you just want to store each output of the select in the `delta_table`, why not just `DELETE FROM delta_table;` before storing the new results again? -- Also, with only this information it seems unlikely to storing the results in a separate table is helpful in any ways. You could use cursors, temp tables or even your client application to process the differences.

Comment: I have given answer that should match your desired results. Not sure if you will be notified about answer because I have deleted and undeleted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it using this SQL:

```
select c1.c_id, 
sum(case when c1.batch_id = 100 then (c1.amount1 * -1) else (c1.amount1 * 1) end) as amount1
from calc_table c1
where c1.batch_id = 100 or c1.batch_id = 101
group by c1.c_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try `FULL JOIN`?

Assuming that batch_id that you calculate delta for are always increments of 1. Something like this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(new.batch_id, old_padded_with_deleted.batch_id) AS batch_id,
       COALESCE(new.c_id, old_padded_with_deleted.c_id) AS c_id,
       COALESCE(new.date, old_padded_with_deleted.date) AS date, --new.amount1, old_padded_with_deleted.amount1,
       CASE WHEN new.amount1 IS NULL THEN -old_padded_with_deleted.amount1 ELSE (new.amount1 - coalesce(old_padded_with_deleted.amount1, 0)) END AS amount1,
       CASE WHEN new.amount2 IS NULL THEN -old_padded_with_deleted.amount2 ELSE (new.amount2 - coalesce(old_padded_with_deleted.amount2, 0)) END AS amount2
FROM calc_table new
FULL JOIN (
  SELECT coalesce(old.batch_id, deleted.batch_id)+1 AS batch_id, coalesce(old.c_id, deleted.c_id) AS c_id, coalesce(old.date, deleted.date) AS date,
         coalesce(old.amount1, deleted.amount1) AS amount1, coalesce(old.amount2, deleted.amount2) AS amount2
  FROM delta_table AS deleted
  FULL JOIN calc_table AS old ON old.batch_id = deleted.batch_id AND old.c_id = deleted.c_id
) AS old_padded_with_deleted ON old_padded_with_deleted.c_id = new.c_id
                        AND old_padded_with_deleted.batch_id = new.batch_id
WHERE
  new.batch_id = 101 OR old_padded_with_deleted.batch_id = 101
```

Comment: it doesn't work, (1) the batch_id is not always incremented by 1. and (2) the difference between amounts is wrong - it should be calculated in the `calc_table`, not from the `delta_table`. (3) i am getting the deleted record, but not the added record.